# Devise: How can I send the confirmable email but not require confirmation by while

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-4.2, devise-confirmable

I wanna send mail to user confirms it, but it's not interesting by now to block users access, although would be amazing to have the control about who confirmed and who did not, and in the future make confirmation required.

Added the block below on my User model, but it makes devise not sending even a mail

```
  protected
  def confirmation_required?
    false
  end
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Y shouldn't have to add anything to your *user.rb*, devise already provides a setting for you to do what you want, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set `config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for = nil` on your *devise.rb* to allow unconfirmed access.

Comment: Source code is the best docs, a "nastier" solution is to set it up for `100.years`.

Comment: I know, but it's hard for maintainers to do it all. Submit a PR, Docs a re a good way to get started into contributing to Open Source.

Comment: of course... its not a critic, just told you I guessed that if it would be an option, it would be in this link, but wasn't, making me not giving this a try 

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-:confirmable-to-Users#allowing-unconfirmed-access